# Convert .avi to .gif with ffmpeg with good quality AND subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, gif, avi, subtitle

I want to use ffmpeg to convert .avi to .gif with good quality **and** subtitles.

Now, I use this script to convert from .avi to .gif with **good quality**:

```
ffmpeg -v warning -ss 10:00 -t 5 -i input.avi -vf "fps=15,scale=420:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen" -y palette.png
ffmpeg -v warning -ss 10:00 -t 5 -i input.avi -i palette.png -lavfi "fps=15,scale=420:-1:flags=lanczos [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y output.gif
```

I generate a palette and then using it to output the gif.

Then I am using this script to add **subtitles** to **gif**:

```
ffmpeg -v warning -i output.gif -vf "ass=subtitles.ass" -y outputWithSubs.gif
```

All that works just fine. The problem is that the first script gives me *good quality without subtitles* and the second gives me *subtitles without good quality*.

When I am trying to combine them with this script:

```
ffmpeg -v warning -ss 10:00 -t 5 -i input.avi -vf "fps=15,scale=420:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen" -y palette.png
ffmpeg -v warning -ss 10:00 -t 5 -i input.avi -i palette.png -vf "ass=subtitles.ass" -lavfi "fps=15,scale=420:-1:flags=lanczos [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y output.gif
```

I am getting this error:

`Filtergraph 'ass=subtitles.ass' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.`

Is there any way that I could combine good quality and subtitles at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`-filter_complex`, not `-vf`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Filtering), and do all of your filtering in one [filtergraph](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1).

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 10:00 -t 5 -i input.avi -filter_complex "fps=15,scale=420:-1:flags=lanczos,ass=subtitles.ass,palettegen" palette.png

ffmpeg -y -ss 10:00 -t 5 -i input.avi -i palette.png -filter_complex "fps=15,scale=420:-1:flags=lanczos,ass=subtitles.ass[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" output.gif
```

Comment: tried it out million times but output does not have subtitle :s

Comment: @0rhodabasi I would need to see your command and console output to provide any suggestions.

Comment: Here is the question that I asked recently about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43440453/subtitle-not-visible-while-converting-gif-with-ffmpeg/