# Subtitle not visible while converting GIF with ffmpeg

Tags: bash, filter, ffmpeg, gif, subtitle

I couldn't make a subtitled gif with a proper quality and a subtitle. Here is my bash script:

```
start_time=00:00:45
duration=5


PALETTE="palette.png"
SUBTITLE="subtitles=sub.srt:force_style='Fontsize=24'"
FILTERS="fps=20,scale=400:-1:flags=lanczos"




ffmpeg -ss $start_time -t $duration -i $1 -vf "$FILTERS,palettegen" -y $PALETTE 
ffmpeg -ss $start_time -t $duration -i $1 -i $PALETTE -lavfi "$FILTERS[x];[x][1:v] paletteuse" -y $2 -vf $SUBTITLE
```

It returns no error, just no subtitle on the output gif. There is a relevant question already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027422/convert-avi-to-gif-with-ffmpeg-with-good-quality-and-subtitles), but it didn't work neither.

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FILTERS should include the subtitles filter.

```
FILTERS="fps=20,scale=400:-1:flags=lanczos,subtitles=sub.srt:force_style='Fontsize=24'"
```

And remove `-vf $SUBTITLE`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XKNHSPfK for first command, https://pastebin.com/Zj0gW1ZF for second command